# Having problem making image a certain shape with css

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a normal shaped image be transformed into the following shape when uploaded to my website:

[image]

Using the following css i managed to get something close to this:

```
.img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: -10rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 10%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 45%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
}
```

But it doesn't really look circular at the bottom and right side., the shape comes out odd.

I basically want the CSS to transform any shaped image uploaded into the right angle/circle shape attached, but I'm struggling. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [css clipping masks](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) to cut the image into shape.

```
clip-path: circle(60% at 30% 30%);
```

[image: Code result]

If you need help creating the mask, use [clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this??

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -150px;
  left: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="circle"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That just makes the image a circle, I need the top corner of it to be a right angle.

Comment: Then we need to put the circle in a box. Check the updated answer